# Flat tires every morning

Tags: tire, puncture

I just bought a new bike. I ride about 3 times a week. The last 2 times I've taken my bike out the front tire has been completely flat. I put air in it the first time it happened and went for a 10mi ride and the tire was still fine. Then next morning it was flat again (same thing the 2nd time).. I recently got into riding and I have no clue about the maintenance and fixing my bike. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you haven't been changing the tubes (sounds like you haven't), I'm going to go with leaky/stuck valve as my first guess and tiny puncture in the tube as my second guess.

Comment: Gidday and welcome to SE Bicycles.  Punctures and leaks are probably the single most common issue on a bike.  Please use the site's search functionality to find existing questions where someone has asked the same or similar things before.

Comment: You might try removing the tube, put a little air in it, and then hold it completely underwater, pools work good for this, a sink or bucket will also do fine, you will see bubbles being formed where your air is escaping.

Comment: I should mention that there are a few exotic brands of "racing" tubes which are ultra-thin and leak down in about 24 hours.  You normally wouldn't have these unless you'd intentionally installed them (though perhaps without knowing the problems they'd cause), but it's vaguely possible that the bike shop sold you a "racer's upgrade" or some such that includes them.  (But the simple "slow leak" problem described by others is far more likely.)

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you have a slow leak, either from the valve or from a tiny puncture in the tube, like Batman mentioned in the comments.

An easy way to fix this is by simply changing the tube in the front tire. If you've never done this before, [this video may help](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fwwfV99VV8I) or you can take your bike into your local bike shop and have someone fix it for you. If you choose the latter of the two, ask if they can teach you how to change out the tube, since this is an invaluable skill to have.

Comment: OP - If you do switch the tube, be sure to drag your hand around the inside of the tire to check for thorns and debris, it will save you ruining a new tube, i have found micro thorns that were nearly to small to see this way. They get stuck in the rubber and penetrate just deep enough to poke the tube creating a slow leak.